# Replace x/y/z to x&z with Emacs?

Tags: emacs, replace

I have a large file like this:

```
x/y/z
x2/y2/z2
...
```

How can I use Emacs's `replace` to change them to

```
x&z 
x2&z2
```

so the '/y/' part is changed to '&'?

Comment: How about going to the top of the buffer and typing?:  `M-x replace-string RET x/y/z RET x&z RET`  Same procedure for the second string.  Or, combine everything into one search and use `C-q C-j` to insert a hard return where appropriate.  Here is a link to the corresponding section in the manual:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Unconditional-Replace.html#Unconditional-Replace

Comment: Here is a programmatic method:  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12136/2287

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you need to replace `/y/` or `/y1/` or `/xxx/` to `&`, you can use `replace-regexp`.

```
M-x replace-regexp <RET> /.*/ <RET> & <RET>
```

This will replace the strings including slashes of both sides to `&`.

You can also use `query-replace-regexp` to replace the matched strings interactively.

Comment: Unless there is a reason to use a broad-brush regexp (i.e., to catch anything and everything between two forward slashes), it is usually advisable to use a narrowly tailored regexp instead -- i.e., a scalpel instead of a machete.